# Why does my oven need to be above 36" if installed in Canada?

Tags: oven

I'm considering this oven for my cabin (in Canada). [Installation manual](https://media3.gaggenau.com/Documents/9000978913_I.pdf) says it needs to be at least 916 mm (36 inch) from the floor. But that applies only in Canada.

Why? What's special about Canada? Is there an actual reason, or is this a code requirement? I was considering having it below counter. If that would be acceptable in the US or Europe, I wonder what the problem would be in Canada.

Comment: The actual reason would be that there's a code requirement specific to Canada... Presumably in CAN/CSA C22.2 No. 150 - Microwave Ovens

Comment: As a Canadian I would find it weird and awkward to have a microwave that low(below a counter).  Only in Canada you say. Pity.

Comment: I get the point about usability and ergonomics, but for [expletive]'s sake, it's a convection oven with microwave add-on. Under the counter it would still already be higher than the conventional oven it replaces... So to me, that would be a good safety step in the right direction. But code seems to forbid it. </rant>

Comment: @Jeffrey  I think it might about how a microwave can heat liquids super hot without boiling in rare cases.  Once a container of super hot liquid is disturb(removing from microwave), it can explode(boil away) upwards.  If a person is bending down at this time, their face would be in the way.  Just guessing at the reason for the height limit and why Canada has it and not other countries.

Comment: The installation instructions require airflow around the back to allow excess heat to escape. If under a counter top, how would air circulate freely up the back and out of the top (of the cupboard)?

Comment: One way is to leave 1 inch on top and put a trim ventilation strip. Louvered aluminum. That's what we did. Another one is to leave a ventilation grate at the far end of the countertop, behind the oven. We discarded this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like they don’t want people bending over to pick up the hot dishes etc.

That is a positioning concept applied in some kitchens when the other ergonomics permit.

Comment: Don't think it is hot dishes, but super hot liquids.  Microwaves can heat liquid up enough in certain rare cases, that when disturb(removing from oven) it can explode up into your face, if you are bending over.

Comment: Our microwave is under the countertop and we like how it is convenient yet out of the way.

Comment: @RetiredATC that is why I phrased it as I did - some places don’t restrict things so much…